# String as xml data source in XQJ

Tags: xquery, saxon, xqj

I would like to parse my XML string using an XQJ implementation, for example, SAXON. All examples I could find refer to some database connections. Is it possible to use simple String as xml source?

Answer (score 1):

Saxon has an XQJ interface, and you could either use the doc function() from XQuery e.g. :

```
XQDataSource ds = new SaxonXQDataSource();
XQConnection conn = ds.getConnection();
XQPreparedExpression exp = conn.prepareExpression("doc('file:/some/file.xml')/child::node()");
XQResultSequence result = exp.executeQuery();
while(result.next()) {
    System.out.println(result.getItemAsString(null));
}
```

or directly inject in the XML into the query. e.g. -

```
XQDataSource ds = new SaxonXQDataSource();
XQConnection conn = ds.getConnection();
XQPreparedExpression exp = conn.prepareExpression("<a><b>test</b></a>/child::node()");
XQResultSequence result = exp.executeQuery();
while(result.next()) {
    System.out.println(result.getItemAsString(null));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
void    XQExpression.bindDocument(javax.xml.namespace.QName varName, javax.xml.transform.Source value, XQItemType type)
```

with XQConstants.CONTEXT_ITEM as the first argument, and a StreamSource wrapping a StringReadeer as the second.